# change <a> element color darkmode.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I add 3 icons from fontawesome and the color of the icons like this:
[image: font awesome icons]

I wanted to make the color of the icons black, but when I add darkmode.js and get the site darkmode, the icons do not change color, they remain black and do not appear.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the text color in dark mode by using the `.darkmode--activated` selector.

As we can't see your html lets suppose this icons have the class `social-icons`, you could create a css rule to change their color to white:

```
.darkmode--activated .social-icons {
  color: white;
}
```